# Place objects randomly within a range in Blender Python

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I have 10 objects, I would like to place these objects randomly within a range x, y, z (with minimum and maximum). Something like that:

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import random
import math

bpy.data.objects["Sasso_1"].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.mass = 0.25

for obj in bpy.data.collections['Sassi'].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=random.uniform(12,27), orient_axis='X')
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=random.uniform(-15,15), orient_axis='Y')
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=random.uniform(13,28), orient_axis='Z')

for obj in bpy.data.collections['Sassi'].all_objects:
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=random.uniform(0,360), orient_axis='X')
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=random.uniform(0,360), orient_axis='Y')
```

In my script, the objects "sassi" rotate and translate in a random way, but not in a range that I want.
The result is that the objects are unpredictable.
Tnx for the attention. :)

Comment: Please share a fully runnable script. Furthermore indicate what goes wrong

Comment: Hi Vasco, I changed the script in the question. Sorry for the mistakes I'm new here. Blender moves objects randomly choosing a number between 12 and 27 (on x), -15 and 15 (on y), etc. I want to move the objects in the range between 12 and 27 (on x) but I mean the x is the range of the location and not the translate value.

Comment: To what range is the object translated?

Answer (score 0):

The translate operator does a relative movement:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.transform.html

In your case you want to set an absolute position. How to do that is explained here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89581

```py
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location.x = 3.0
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location.y = 2.0
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location.z = 1.0
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem with the randomize trasform function.
this is the code for do it:

```
bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform(random_seed = random.randint(0,100), loc=(6, 6, 6), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```